# PlotLegend[ not working]

Tags: legending

I am trying to use plotlegend for solutions I've obtained using NDSolve. I have

```
Plot[{a[z], b[z]} /. sol , {z, 0, L}, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2"}]
```

It doesn't work because I am using ./sol

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate `Evaluate` is required. Does `Plot[Evaluate[{a[z], b[z]}/.sol], {z, 0, L}, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2"}]` work?

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate the list first:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{a[z], b[z]} /. sol] , {z, 0, L}, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2"}]
```